# Get HTML Equivalent of Google Doc contents

Tags: google-apps, google-docs-api

I am trying to get the HTML for a Google Doc's contents.  The methods I have found all seem to use deprecated items.  I ultimately want to use the Doc as a template for an email. I have everything working except getting the HTML version of the text. Yes, I want the full HTML version including tables, images, and anything else I can place in the Doc.

Is there any way to get this?

Regards,

Karl S

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following method works:

1. Open up the Google Doc you want to work with
2. Click `File`-->`Publish to the web`
3. Click `Link` and then `Publish`
4. Copy the link into another tab
5. View the source for the page and copy everything inside and including `<div id="contents">`

This should be the complete HTML for that document. I just verified that it works with a document of mine. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking to do this in a script.  Maybe my tags are not correct.